# Finding correct bounds for integral to evaluate probability

Tags: probability, definite-integrals

I have a bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ with density given by $f(x,y)=e^{-x}$, $0<y<x$.

I need to evaluate $P(X<2-Y)$, but I am having trouble finding the correct bounds on which to evaluate the integral required to find the answer.

The solution is given as 
$$P(X<2-Y)=\int_0^1 \int_0^x e^{-x} \, dydx + \int_1^2 \int_0^{2-x} e^{-x} \, dydx$$

but I cannot see why the region of integration needs to be split up like it is.

I am not sure what I should graph to be able to see that these bounds are correct. Any hints as to how I should proceed are appreciated?

Comment: By setting things up so that one integrates first w.r.t. $x$, we can avoid a split integral.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think I found out how to proceed. I first drew the region given by 0<y<x, and then the region given by x< 2 - y. Then the necessary region for the integral is the intersection of the two above inequalities. Is this correct?

Comment: I was busy typing! As you will see, the answer stresses doing exactly what you did, drawing a picture.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was forgetting to include the initial inequality when graphing. Remembering it lead to me to the correct answer. I will add the pictures shortly and mark this as answered.

Comment: Many thanks for the picture. It will make the answer far more useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let us identify the region where the joint density function "lives." We are told that $0\lt y\lt x$. **Draw** the line $y=x$. The density function lives in the part of the first quadrant that is *below* the line $y=x$.

Now let us look at the condition $X\lt 2-Y$, which I prefer to rewrite as $X+Y\lt 2$. **Draw** the line $x+y=2$. We want to find the probability that the pair $(X,Y)$ ends up *below* the line.

Now look at the region $K$ which is in the first quadrant, below the line $y=x$, and below the line $x+y=2$. This is a **triangle** with corners $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$, and $(1,1)$.  We are integrating $e^{-x}$ over the triangle.

[image: Graph of regions]

Suppose that we decide to integrate first with respect to $x$, and then with respect to $y$. If $0\lt x\lt 1$, then $y$ goes from $0$ to $x$, because when we hit the line $y=x$, we leave $K$.  But from $x=1$ to $x=2$, we start at $y=0$, and as we go up we leave $K$ when we hit the bounding line $x+y=2$.  That analysis will give the solution that you quoted.

But note that we could first integrate with respect to $x$. For any $y$ between $0$ and $1$, we enter the region $K$ at $x=y$, and leave it at $x+y=2$, that is, $x=2-y$. So an alternative way to compute the probability is as
$$\int_{y=0}^1\left(\int_{x=y}^{2-y} e^{-x}\,dx                 \right)\,dy.$$
As a bonus, the mechanical details of the integration are easier!